# Calculate dots on cuboid's grid

Tags: java, math, bukkit

I have an issue with my math skills here. So I need to calculate the positions (x, y, z) of a specific amount of dots per aixs. For example take this image[image]

```
final double gapX = lengthX / dotsPerXAxis;
final double gapY = lengthY / dotsPerYAxis;
final double gapZ = lengthZ / dotsPerZAxis;

for (BlockFace blockFace : BlockHandler.DIRECT_RELATIVES) {
    final DecimalVector3D minCorner = new DecimalVector3D(
        blockFace.getModX(),
        blockFace.getModY(),
        blockFace.getModZ()
    );

for (int x = 0; x < dotsPerXAxis || x == 0; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < dotsPerYAxis; y++) {
        for (int z = 0; z < dotsPerZAxis; z++) {

        }
    }
}
```

My question now is: how can I iterate over all the dots except those that are inside the cuboid and calculate their position and put them in an ImmutableList?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to treat point if at least one coordinate of it is zero or `dotsPerZAxis`.

So set flags - if X-coordinate lies on face, if Y-coordinate lies on face. If both flags **are not set** - get only the first and the last Z-coordinates, otherwise walk through all Z-coordinates.

Unchecked Java:

```
for (int x = 0; x < dotsPerXAxis; x++) {
    bool atX = (x == 0) || (x == dotsPerXAxis - 1);
    for (int y = 0; y < dotsPerYAxis; y++) {
        bool atY = (y == 0) || (y == dotsPerYAxis - 1);

        int zstep = (atX || atY)? 1: dotsPerZAxis - 1;

        for (int z = 0; z < dotsPerZAxis; z+=zstep) {
           treat(x,y,z)
        }
    }
}
```

[Ideone Python working code as proof-of-concept](https://ideone.com/8g0AMw) gives `n^3 - (n-2)^3` points (26 surface points for n=3, 56 for n=4, 98 for n=5)

Comment: that just throws a java heap exception for me

Comment: also I think you forgot that I only need the dots on the outside and have to ignore those on the inside

Comment: No, I don't forget. You can see at ideone that Python code produces only outer points. I don't know Java, so it is better  to understand approach and make corrections

Answer (score 0):

Based on the help of MBo I figured this out

```
    for (BlockFace blockFace : BlockHandler.DIRECT_RELATIVES) {
        for (int x = 0; x < dotsPerXAxis || x == 0 || x == dotsPerXAxis - 1; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < dotsPerXAxis || y == 0 || y == dotsPerYAxis - 1; y++) {
                for (int z = 0; z < dotsPerXAxis || z == 0;
                     z += (y == 0 || y == dotsPerYAxis - 1) || (x == 0 || x == dotsPerXAxis - 1) ? 1 :
                         dotsPerZAxis - 1) {

                    results.add(new DecimalVector3D(
                        x,
                        y,
                        z
                    ));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is no sense in all these pieces in for's:  `|| x == 0 || x == dotsPerXAxis - 1`. And... it's strange that you did mark own answer when all meaningful logic was presented in mine.

Comment: I specifically asked for java so I answered the question with the corresponding Java code

Comment: OMG... Marking own solution is pretty nice when you implemented own ideas. But here you have rewritten my code (preserving copy-paste mistakes - I corrected dotsPerXAxis in y and z for's just now) and added unnecessary conditions...